# valgrind output does not provide function name, or line number of the memory leaks

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I've seen a few posts regarding this but none of the solutions seem to work for me.
I am compiling my code using this makefile:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -O0 -std=c++11
OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIRS = `pkg-config --cflags opencv4`
OPENCV_LIBS = `pkg-config --libs opencv4`
JETSON_GPIO_INCLUDE_DIRS = -I/usr/include/JetsonGPIO
JETSON_GPIO_LIBS = -lJetsonGPIO


SOURCES := $(wildcard *.cpp)
HEADERS := $(wildcard *.h)
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o)

%.o: %.cpp $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIRS) $(JETSON_GPIO_INCLUDE_DIRS) -c $< -o $@

program: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o program $^ $(OPENCV_LIBS) $(JETSON_GPIO_LIBS) -lpthread
```

meaning i am running g++ with `-g -O0` arguments.

I am running valgrind with:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all   --verbose --log-file=valgrind-out2.txt  ./program
```

so I don't understand why my valgrind output is this:

```
==18802== 5,520 bytes in 55 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 6 of 18
==18802==    at 0x484622C: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm64-linux.so)
==18802== 
==18802== 18,453 (18,413 direct, 40 indirect) bytes in 927 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 7 of 18
==18802==    at 0x4845BFC: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm64-linux.so)
==18802== 
==18802== 28,896 bytes in 607 blocks are still reachable in loss record 8 of 18
==18802==    at 0x5ED2DDC: g_type_create_instance (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.5600.4)
==18802== 
==18802== 57,344 bytes in 7 blocks are still reachable in loss record 9 of 18
==18802==    at 0x48468F4: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm64-linux.so)
==18802== 
==18802== 59,944 (54,424 direct, 5,520 indirect) bytes in 923 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 10 of 18
==18802==    at 0x484622C: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm64-linux.so)
```

so i don't know what generates the leak.
i don't use `new` in my code, i only use smart pointers when i have to and i don't have any dynamic initialisation. i've followed many of the basic c++ memory handling and my memory leak isnt the worst but i still would rather have none of course.
if anyone knows what i am doing wrong in compiling/using valgrind i would really appreciate help with this

Comment: Does `JetsonGPIO` and any other libraries include debugging information/symbols ?

Comment: hmm i haven't thought about JetsonGPIO or OpenCV or pthread not being in debug mode. maybe i am required to rebuild them in debug? but then maybe the leak is in their functions so unless i change the source codes i can't fix it? or am i understanding it wrong

Comment: If you find a memory leak in a third-party library you use (in your case JetsonGPIO and OpenCV) then you create a proper [mre] and report it to the library maintainers. If you *can* fix the leak (and have the time to do it) then you could add a patch to your issue.

Comment: i will do a few simple checks for both libraries to check for memory leaks but does the valgrind output means the leak is definitely 3rd party or is there something wrong with how i am using it and there still might be a leak in my code?

Comment: Valgrind points towards where the memory that was leaked was first allocated - for obvious reasons it cannot point to where it should have been deleted. So if any of your libraries allocate stuff for you *that you were supposed to free yourself*, then Valgrind will still point to the library. At least as far as I understand it.

Comment: yes i do understand it points to where it was first alocated, problem is, you can see it only specified the memory leak "at" not "by", meaning it isn't pointing to anything, just shows where valgrind saw the memory issue, thats what "at" shows from my understanding